# How does Python manage memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management, pybind11

When Python del pybind11 encapsulates objects, memory is not returned to the system, but is stored in a memory pool. If it is an object in Python, it will return memory to the operating system,Can someone tell me the reason for this situation.Due to some reasons, I am unable to display the complete code. Please allow me to use relevant pseudo code for display

pybind11 code

```
def observe_mem_func():
  print('Memory already in use:',
        psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss // 1024 // 1024 // 1024)


#  Display the memory used by the system before initializing the pybind11 object
observe_mem_func()
# The init_pybind_object function will return two pybind11 encapsulated objects
pybind_object_1, pybind_object_2 = init_pybind_object()
# Display the memory used by the system after initializing the pybind11 object
observe_mem_func()

# Del pybind11 object
del pybind_object_1
del pybind_object_2
gc.collect()
# Display the memory used by the system after del the pybind11 object
observe_mem_func()

# Once initialized again, it can be seen that the memory was taken out of the memory pool, 
# which means that the memory has not been returned to the system
pybind_object_3, pybind_object_4 = init_pybind_object()
observe_mem_func()

# -------Display code run results ------
# The memory unit is G
Memory already in use: 0
Memory already in use: 1
Memory already in use: 1
Memory already in use: 1
```

python code

```
def observe_mem_func():
  print('Memory already in use:',
        psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss // 1024 // 1024 )
class Base:

  def __init__(self, str) -> None:
    self.str = str

def init_base():
  with open("test_code/file.txt", 'r') as fp:
    return Base(fp.read())

a = []
print("Init Base object")
for i in range(5):
  a.append(init_base())
  observe_mem_func()

print("Del object")
for i in range(5):
  a.pop()
  observe_mem_func()
  
# -------Display code run results ------
# The memory unit is M
# According to the results, the memory was returned to the operating system
Init Base object
Memory already in use: 215
Memory already in use: 246
Memory already in use: 277
Memory already in use: 307
Memory already in use: 338
Del object
Memory already in use: 307
Memory already in use: 277
Memory already in use: 246
Memory already in use: 215
Memory already in use: 185
```

Comment: Try `gc.collect()` to force garbage collector to run a full collection. Also what `init_pybind_object` doing?

Comment: 1:I tried using gc.collect() and the results were the same. 2:The init_pybind_object function will return two pybind11 encapsulated objects @Alex

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, CPython uses regular `malloc` and the observed behavior is consistent with that. The second example allocates one huge block of memory for the `str` object. Allocations above a threshold are directly allocated (memory-mapped) and returned to the OS. Small allocations are reused and only released to the OS when the heap shrinks significantly (and is not fragmented). The memory usage in your two examples are different by orders of magnitude. That is relevant here.

Comment: Good summary on glibc's malloc implementation: https://azeria-labs.com/heap-exploitation-part-1-understanding-the-glibc-heap-implementation/

Comment: @Homer512 sorry I have updated my description. The unit of the first example is G, and the unit of the second example is M.

Comment: @Homer512 In the first example, there may be a lot of fragmented memory in the pybind11 object, and the final initialized object has a total memory of 1GB. I'm not sure if this situation meets what you're saying

Comment: Not seeing more that one decimal place in the first example still limits the assessment. And yes, many small allocations will affect the result. The heap can only shrink at the tail end. A single active object near that end can prevent this from happening. Normally that isn't an issue because the application will ultimately reuse the memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255874/discussion-between-dylan-and-homer512).